# How to handle Lambda function heavy job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I have AWS lambda function that gets details using multiple ids via rest API. The problem is the API only accept 1 id at a time/per call. Per my observation, the job can only cater around 30 ids else the job won’t finish or would max my 10 mins time limit. Currently, my ids can go as high as 200 ids per job process so I’m thinking of a way how I can resolve this issue.

So far I’m thinking of using step function so I can asynchronously run the job  and just chunked my ids into multiple payload but I’m not sure how I can pass ids/payload from lambda to step function. Another solution I’m thinking is I can invoke the same lambda with chunked ids but i’m afraid that recursive would happen.

Any other suggestions or AWS services I can use to fix this?

Comment: Can you access persistent storage such as a DynamoDB table? If so, one way would be to save state to pick up, in conjunction with step functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a process that dumps all the IDs into an SQS queue. Then have a Lambda function that uses the [SQS queue as an event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html). Lambda will then automatically spin up multiple instances of your Lambda function, passing each one a batch of IDs to process.